# Problem updating homebrew

Tags: homebrew

Trying to update homebrew, I get this:

```
$ brew update

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    .gitignore
    Library/Contributions/brew_bash_completion.sh
    Library/Contributions/brew_fish_completion.fish
    Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh
    Library/Contributions/manpages/brew.1.md
    Library/ENV/4.3/cc
    Library/ENV/4.3/make
    Library/ENV/4.3/xcrun
    Library/ENV/libsuperenv.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    CONTRIBUTING.md
    Library/Aliases/ag
    Library/Aliases/heroku
```

... etc...

Any way to just clean that up? Looks like it's using git under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on whether you care about local changes to those files. Did you change them yourself, or did you run a program that changed them, or something else?

If you didn't mean to change them at all, `cd /usr/local` and run `git reset --hard HEAD`; this will reset them all to their original state. Then try updating Homebrew.

Comment: I didn't change them intentionally. I have no idea what any of those files are even for! I'm wondering if they could have been changed by a previous aborted homebrew operation - does that sound plausible?

Comment: I definitely think that's plausible, but I think you should maybe raise this issue on the Homebrew GitHub page and see if they have a clear picture of what's going on here.